# How to simplify Q promise example

Tags: javascript, promise, deferred, q

I was working on a simple application that makes sequential
ajax calls, passing result of first call into the next one.

Of course I don't want to go into the callback hell, 
and therefore look into [Promises/A+](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/) spec example and [Q library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

I have prepared an async function that should result in what I want.
But I want an insight on how I can simplify the Sequential promise passing.

For now I am still reading on how to best work with promises and deferred objects, so forgive 
me for the very naive code.

So now I am looking at two things:

- the way to simplify the sequencing of promises (that depend on one
  another as in my case)
- suggestions

  ```
  var modifyableObject = {
      toProcess : ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
  }


  function returnsDeferredResults(someResult) {

      var deferred = Q.defer();

      // my async function (setTimeout for now will do, $.ajax() later)
      setTimeout(function () {

          var nextResult = (someResult || " Initial_Blank_Value ") + "..." + modifyableObject.toProcess[0]; 

          modifyableObject.toProcess = modifyableObject.toProcess.splice(1);

          console.log("New Tick Result: ", nextResult, "Array: ", modifyableObject.toProcess);

          deferred.resolve( nextResult);

      }, 200);

      return deferred.promise;
  }


  //$("#test_promise").click(function () {

      function getDeferredResult(prevResult) {
          return returnsDeferredResults(prevResult);
      }

      var prevResult = getDeferredResult();

      var nextTick = "";

      for (var i = modifyableObject.toProcess.length; i > 1; i --) {

          if (nextTick) 
              nextTick = nextTick.then(getDeferredResult);
          else 
              nextTick = prevResult.then(getDeferredResult);
      }

      //nextTick.fin(function(){ ...});

  //});



  /*
  New Tick Result:   Initial_Blank_Value ...one           Array:  ["two", "three", "four", "five"]
  New Tick Result:   Initial_Blank_Value ...one...two            Array:  ["three", "four", "five"]
  New Tick Result:   Initial_Blank_Value ...one...two...three             Array:  ["four", "five"] 
  New Tick Result:   Initial_Blank_Value ...one...two...three...four              Array:  ["five"]
  New Tick Result:   Initial_Blank_Value ...one...two...three...four...five             Array:  [] 
  */
  ```

Thank you everyone in advance!

Comment: I don't really get why you're using promises here. Their point should be not to need globals like `modifyableObject` any more.

Comment: this is just a prototype code that is simplified and put into "global" scope. I will use `$.ajax()` instead of `setTimeout` function and `modifyableObject` will be replaced with data that I need to pass into the `$.ajax()` call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simplify your loop by combining the two variables:

```
var nextTick = getDeferredResult();

for (var i = modifyableObject.toProcess.length; i > 1; i --) {
    nextTick = nextTick.then(getDeferredResult);
}
```

Or,

```
return modifyableObject.toProcess.reduce(function(promise, item) {
    return promise.then(getDeferredResult);
}, Q.resolve());
```

---

You can simplify your function too:

```
return Q.delay(200).then(function) { 
    return "..." + modifyableObject.toProcess.shift();
});
```

jQuery AJAX also returns a promise, which Q is compatible with (in recent versions of jQuery)

You can then combine the two improvements by passing each item to the function:

```
return modifyableObject.toProcess.reduce(function(promise, item) {
    return promise.then(processItem.bind(null, item));
}, Q.resolve());

function processItem(item) {
    return Q.delay(200).then(function) { 
        return "..." + modifyableObject.toProcess.shift();
    });
}
```

Comment: wow, such an awesome response! I really like the way you use reduce function on promise and push then method on it. This is what I was looking for :P

Comment: This is such an awesome pattern; it should be documented in the Q docs, IMO.